# How to read .xlsb file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, xlsb

I'm connected to a File System Linked Service where the .xlsb file is and I want to create a CSV file with that information.

This .xlsb file has several sheets and I only need one.

Is it possible to read .xlsb files and select the sheet that we want in Data Factory dataset and copy data activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not possible to select `.xlsb` file as source in Azure Data Factory.

Only the following document types are allowed.

[image]

**Workaround:-**

You can convert `.xlsb` file to excel file, there are lot of tools available on the Internet.

Then you can Select `Name` or `Index` in `Worksheet mode` as shown in below image.

[image]

For reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel